# overlay in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, overlay

Hey as I am pretty new to angular, I am trying to create an overlay in angularJs.

I got the overlay running when I leave everything in the original controller.
But for the sake of reusability I'd like to extract the html and jsCode into different files. 
What is the best possible way for that.

I tried it with a new controller but as far as I understand it I cannot inject the controller and just call the functions.

```
anuglar.module('myModule')
       .controller('MyController1', MyController1);

myController1.$inject = ['$scope', 'MyController2'];

function MyController1 ($scope, MyController2){
    myController2.displayOverlay();
}
```

Second Controller which handles overlay:

```
anuglar.module('myModule')
       .controller('MyController2', MyController2);

myController1.$inject = ['$scope'];

function MyController2 ($scope){
    function displayOverlay(){
     //do stuff
    }
}
```

Working with angular 1.6
Thanks for your advice

Comment: (additionally) external injection is done differently: `myController1.$inject = [...];`

Comment: thx fixed it oversaw that